# Installing Nuget Gets Dependencies Only

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a .NET Framework 4.5 project.  I'm trying to install Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.  This should be possible as per https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk/

I ran the following command, but get the dependencies only.  I tried installing via the Nuget Package Manager too. Finally... I see the package inside my packages.config file, but don't see it in my references. Any suggestions?

```
Install-Package Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk -Version 15.7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.